# Alternative for Mac OS X Automator?

Tags: automation, alternative, scripts, workflow

I once tested Mac OS X and something that called my atention was Automator, a software to visually create scripts to automatize tasks on the desktop. Is there any Linux alternative for this software?

Comment: There seem to be a lot of answers suggesting tools for automating inputs to GUIs, for instance as one would see in test automation. This is not what the question is asking about. Please have some understanding of the Automator software in Mac OS X when answering. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_macOS_components#Automator

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is Gnu Xnee, which enables you to record and replay actions on the desktop. You can install it from the software center.

"GNU Xnee is a suite of programs that can record, replay and
distribute user actions under the X11 environment. Think of it as a
robot that can imitate the job you just did."

Comment: Or click here: http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xnee

Comment: how to launch xnee, I'v installed xnee as sell as Gnee. from terminal Gnee shows error and xnee isn't a command

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's `xnee` and its version with a GUI `gnee`.

You can find it in the software center or install it via

```
sudo apt-get install gnee
```

Screenshots and documentation are available on the [GNU xnee](http://www.sandklef.com/xnee/?q=node&q=gnee-screenshot) page.

Answer (score 4):

If you're feeling adventurous, you could try out [Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/). It's a computer-vision-based, cross-platform GUI automator with a slick IDE. It wasn't developed on Linux, so the Linux documentation is a little thin; however, it's pretty intuitive, and most of the non-Linux documentation applies.

Answer (score 2):

As a third solution, you can take the trip to the Java world by taking a look at [Actions](http://app.jbbres.com/index.html), which closely mimics Automator look and feel.

Comment: Well, it seems like it is not meant for Linux. Maybe it was at some point given it's Java roots.

Answer (score 1):

The options mentioned above all sound okay, and I've tried gnee - but Xpresser seems to be quite reliable and easy to use, if you don't mind a bit of scripting.

[Youtube Video Demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-xxBBPU9kU)

[Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Xpresser)