# Are there other Automator alternatives?

Tags: software-recommendation, desktop-recording

I want something that records (like Macro) the GUI actions and keystrokes that can be played later to accomplish same actions. Something like Automator in OS X.

I have already looked into [Alternative for Mac OS X Automator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343/alternative-for-mac-os-x-automator)
I have tried Gnee, but that doesn't seem to work,tried several times but I guess its kinda buggy, I also tried Sikuli but that needs coding.

Comment: what do you mean buggy? please be exact.

Comment: I have already discussed about the Gnee not working in one of my earlier question, and the programme doesn't work ie. when I press record, it disappears and I cant find it anywhere, I can then only open it once again with a fresh window.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [AutoKey](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=autokey-gtk)? It can do quite a lot of keyboard interference through abbreviations and hotkeys. It's less focussed on GUI interactions but if the application in question has keyboard shortcuts, it can use them.

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

Comment: The action may not be commands, so I guess this wont work as you are saying less GUI focus and keyboard shortcuts, But I'll look into it.